# Creating a history page with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, search, react-hooks, history

I am trying to create a history page with react hooks that keeps track of the users most recent searches they don't have to be persistent through refreshes only from this session.

my search component looks like this this is a simple app that does not need a UI just a simple navigation on the search page it will show the results and on the history page I would like to be able to show the previous searches from this session

I am trying to keep track of the debouncedTerm so I can display it in a new component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Search = () => {
  const history = [];
  const [term, setTerm] = useState('');
  const [debouncedTerm, setDebouncedTerm] = useState(term);
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedTerm(term);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    };
  }, [term]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const search = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get('http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?', {
        params: {
          query: debouncedTerm,
        },
      });

      setResults(data.hits);
    };
    if (debouncedTerm) {
      search();
    }
  }, [debouncedTerm]);

  const renderedResults = results.map((result) => {
    return (
      <div key={result.objectID} className="item">
        <div className="right floated content">
          <a className="ui button" href={result.url}>
            Go
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="content">
          <div className="header">{result.title}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="ui form">
        <div className="field">
          <label>Hacker News Search:</label>
          <input
            value={term}
            onChange={(e) => setTerm(e.target.value)}
            className="input"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="ui celled list">{renderedResults}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it's going in the right direction but you have a constant `const history = [];` and you must keep in mind that this will not work, because you will have a new constant re-declared in every render. You must use React setState like so:

`const [history, setHistory] = useState([]);`

You can read more about it in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

**edit:**
In order to add new elements to the existing history you have to append it like this:

```js
setHistory(oldHistory => [...oldHistory, newHistoryElement]);
```

Comment: I am still confused as on how to add to the history array each time the API does a search. When I initiate a new search it always removes what is in the array originally. Thank you for the help

Comment: Hi! No problem, I just added an edit to my answer with a way for you to keep the old data and add new one.

Comment: @Shiva Did my answer fixed your problem? Please let us now so we can help you out! :)